# How to access .yml file at root in Netlify CMS?

Tags: yaml, netlify-cms

I'm trying to give Netlify CMS access to a data file containing authors for a blog site, but I haven't been able to get the records from the root of the file. I need the records to be at the root because of the site generator I'm using. Is there anything I can replace the asterisks with to accomplish this?

```
- name: "settings"
    label: "Settings"
    files:
      - name: "authors"
        label: "Authors"
        file: "_data/authors.yml"
        fields:
          - name: "*****"
            label: "Authors"
            widget: "list"
            fields:
              - {label: "Name", name: "name", widget: "string"}
              - {label: "Last Name", name: "last_name", widget: "string"}
              - {label: "First Name", name: "first_name", widget: "string"}
              - {label: "Display Name", name: "display_name", widget: "string"}
              - {label: "Bio", name: "bio", widget: "markdown"}
```

Comment: What do you mean, "records to be at the root"? You need just a list not an object containing a list to be the root element?